# Overloaded routes in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to have the following urls generated

```
http://example.com/routes/A
```

and

```
http://example.com/routes/alpha-to-beta
```

and for this implementation, i have added two routes to `Global.asax` file

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "routes", // Route name
  "routes/{routeName}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "busroute", action = "SingleRoute" } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "alpharoutes", // Route name
  "routes/{alphRoute}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "busroute", action = "AlphabetRoute"  } // Parameter defaults
);
```

However, this does not work as intended. Click on a link takes me to the first registered action only.

Please suggest what is wrong with this implementation.

Comment: How would a computer determine the difference between a `{routeName}` and a `{alphRoute}`, because I'm a human, and I don't see a difference.

Comment: I agree .. what should be the correct approach.... in one case i want to pass a string and in another case i want it to be a char. One way is to check if the passed in value is a string or char and then perform the operation. Is there anyother way?

Answer (score 1):

You need a Route Constraint:

```
public class SingleCharacterConstraint: IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match
        (
            HttpContextBase httpContext, 
            Route route, 
            string parameterName, 
            RouteValueDictionary values, 
            RouteDirection routeDirection
        )
    {
        if (!values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
          return false;

        var parameterValue = (string)values[parameterName];

        return !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(parameterValue)
          && parameterValue.Length == 1;
    }
}
```

Then reorder your maps, and add the constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "alpharoutes", // Route name
  "routes/{alphRoute}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "busroute", action = "AlphabetRoute"  }, // Parameter defaults
  new { alphRoute = new SingleCharacterConstraint() }, // Constraint 
);

routes.MapRoute(
 "routes", // Route name
 "routes/{routeName}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "busroute", action = "SingleRoute" } // Parameter defaults
);
```